# Mudar a tab activa em um p:tabview

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-3.5

Como mudar a `tab` ativa num componente `p:tabview` a partir de um `p:commandButton`?

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já achei a solução:

Utilizar a função `select(index)` do componente para definir a próxima `p:tab` ativa. Esta função é executada no lado do cliente (`javascript`) e é invocada pela referência `widgetVar` do `tabView`.

Answer (score 0):

No componente **tabView** você pode declarar um **widgetVar** (Que é uma variável que pode realizar alterações no front end para o usuário).

Utilizando este **widgetVar** declarado você possui acesso a funções, você pode consultar essas funções digitando: `PF('valor do widgetVar').` no console do navegador e apertando `Crtl+space`.

Uma dessas funções é o **select()**, com ele você informa o índice do Tab a qual você quer que esteja ativo.

Ex.:

```
<p:tabView prependId="false" activeIndex="0" widgetVar="tabsIndice" id="tabs">
    <p:tab title="Tab1" id="Tab1">
        <div>Teste 1</div>
        <p:commandButton value="Atualizar tab" process="Tab1" 
                         action="#{controller.metodoController()}" update="@form" 
                         oncomplete="PF('tabsIndice').select(0)"/>
    </p:tab> 
    <p:tab title="Tab2" id="Tab2">
        <div>Teste 2</div>
        <p:commandButton value="Atualizar tab" process="Tab2" 
                         action="#{controller.metodoController()}" update="@form"  
                         oncomplete="PF('tabsIndice').select(1)"/>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```